# How to use the keyboard to navigate a page on one display while typing on a different display in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, shortcut

I have a multi-monitor setup and want to be able to type into a shell on one monitor while I have a document pulled up on the other monitor, and I want to scroll through the document without my hands leaving the keyboard or interrupting the flow of typing into the shell. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I am running OS X Monterey on a 2019 MBP.

Comment: I can't think of anything more sophisticated than an Automator Applescript as a Service, set to bring the other app to the front, scroll a bit, then bring your original app back to the front. The functionality you have with the mouse scrollwheel over any window just doesn't have a keyboard alternative.

Comment: I've found that if you have one app focused (keyboarding in that app) and then hover over another window you can use the scroll wheel on the non-focused window. That is as close as I have ever come.

Comment: @SteveChambers you can *always* use the scroll wheel on unfocused windows. That's been a Mac feature since Noah was wondering if it might rain ;)